# Python: General CSV file parsing and manipulation

Tags: python, csv

The purpose of my Python script is to compare the data present in multiple CSV files, looking for discrepancies. The data are ordered, but the ordering differs between files. The files contain about 70K lines, weighing around 15MB. Nothing fancy or hardcore here. Here's part of the code:

```
def getCSV(fpath):
    with open(fpath,"rb") as f:
        csvfile = csv.reader(f)

        for row in csvfile:
            allRows.append(row)

allCols = map(list, zip(*allRows))
```

- Am I properly reading from my CSV files? I'm using `csv.reader`, but would I benefit from using `csv.DictReader`?
- How can I create a list containing whole rows which have a certain value in a precise column?

Comment: A single question in StackOverflow should be a _single_, narrowly scoped, clearly and tersely described question, generic enough to benefit others. A rambling narrative, not so much.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The reason I wrote a "rambling narrative" is precisely because a lot of questions I've read were _not_ clear.

Comment: Granted -- but achieving clarity calls for focused prose; otherwise, one adds noise, not illumination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to be keeping all rows around? This creates a list with matching values only... `fname` could also come from `glob.glob()` or `os.listdir()` or whatever other data source you so choose. Just to note, you mention the 20th column, but row[20] will be the 21st column...

```
import csv

matching20 = []

for fname in ('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin)
        next(csvin) # <--- if you want to skip header row
        for row in csvin:
            if row[20] == 'value':
                matching20.append(row) # or do something with it here
```

You only want `csv.DictReader` if you have a header row and want to access your columns by name.

Comment: This works, thanks. My file _does_ have a header row, but I already know the column numbers that interest me.

Comment: @CHM edited answer to include skipping of header row if required

Answer (score 2):

This should work, you don't need to make another list to have access to the columns.

```
import csv
import sys

def getCSV(fpath):
    with open(fpath) as ifile:
        csvfile = csv.reader(ifile)

        rows = list(csvfile)

    value_20 = [x for x in rows if x[20] == 'value']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to include a row if `value` is in the row, but you don't know which column `value` is, correct?

If your rows are lists, then this should work:

```
testlist = [row for row in allRows if 'value' in row]
```

post-edit:

If, as you say, you want a list of rows where `value` is in a specified column (specified by an integer `pos`, then:

```
testlist = []
pos = 20
for row in allRows:
    testlist.append([element if index != pos else 'value' for index, element in enumerate(row)])
```

(I haven't tested this, but let me now if that works).

Comment: @CHM Ahh. That? That one sentence above? *That* is a useful, focused problem description.

Comment: @CHM If that one sentence is what you needed to convey what your question was actually about? When the intended meaning gets buried in the surrounding prose, yes, it's too long.

Comment: @weirdcanada it didn't work, but Jon Clements' answer worked. Thanks anyway!